# How to change a links background image in css

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a CSS sheet inside an HTML document to change the background
image of a link.

You can make CSS make it so if you have your mouse go over something it can like change its color

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#a1:link, #a1:visited {
  background-color:red;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#a1:hover, #a1:active {
  background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <a id="a1" href="home.html">   
 </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to instead doing a color can you do an image?
I have tried 
background-image:url('locationtoimage.jpg')
and it just makes the link disappear. I did change both 
background colors to background-image and I did the proper format and things but it wont work? I have tried googling it but everyone just asks for like buttons to things but I am dealing with links.

Sorry if this was already answered somewhere else. I tried looking but I cant find anything. I am really sure that this is possible and simple and I might just be over looking something. Here is what I have.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#a1:link, #a1:visited {
  background-image:url('media.jpg');
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#a1:hover, #a1:active {
  background-image:url('home.jpg');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <a id="a1" href="home.html">   
 </a>
</body>
</html>
```

this works though

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
   #a1 {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
    #a1:link, #a1:visited {
      background-image:url('imageatasite');
      padding: 15px 25px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    #a1:hover, #a1:active {
      background-image:url('imageatasite');
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="a1" href="home.html">            
        </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but I am not using an image online im using one that is in my html folder 
but it wont work?

Comment: Should work fine. Maybe `home.jpg` is not found? Check the network tab in F12. Could be something as silly as wrong capitals in the filename.

Comment: I will go try and check. I did try width and things like that but it still stays invisible. I  took it out of its div block and it still stays invisible?

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what you said and replaced the url link with the link to my html document. the image is named home.jpg and media.jpg but they are both in the same folder as the main html file so I just say home.jpg and media.jpg but it end up invisible?

Comment: So, not errors in your developer tools? And is it immediately invisible, or only on hover?

Comment: why not using something like this? https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive ;  you could set the image to invisible then on hover to visible

Answer (score 0):

Try googling an image and pasting that in the background image url to see if it's defientley not the file.

Failing that I would suggest to use a separate div wrapper to wrap the images. And on :hover use display none to hide the image you don't want to see on hover.

Then you can set the image to be 100% that of the div. 
Check the file extension too just to be sure.

Comment: This doesnt seem to make sence. So the html document is on my computer in a folder with all the pictures. I went online and I got a pictures link and it worked but my photos dont? They work well for other things like for backgrounds of things but they wont work for this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand what the problem is but other images do work. The images I wanted to use were the same file extension in the same folder but I took a snapshot of them and now they work just fine. Thank you for helping guys I think all is well now.